# How can I generate strings 'a'..'zzz' and then save them to the table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I generate the strings `'a'` through `'zzz'` and then save them to a table using MySQL?

Comment: Why would you want a database to do this. Databases are about storing information. What is the real question - ie why do you want/need to do this.

Comment: Do you really need the alpha ID - you do realize that there are only 17576 possibly unique keys with 3 char lower case key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit difficult to do from "pure" MySQL for two reasons:

- No support for recursive queries, forcing you to use temporary table to generate all possible [variations](http://users.telenet.be/vdmoortel/dirk/Maths/PermVarComb.html).
- However, a temporary table [can't be referenced multiple times from the same query](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327), so you can't use a Cartesian product (i.e. CROSS JOIN) on it to generate the variations. This forces you to use the "real" table instead of the temporary.

In light of all that, the solution would look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP_CHARS (
    C CHAR PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO TEMP_CHARS VALUES('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d'), ('e'), ('f'), ('g'), ('h'), ('i'), ('j'), ('k'), ('l'), ('m'), ('n'), ('o'), ('p'), ('q'), ('r'), ('s'), ('t'), ('u'), ('v'), ('w'), ('x'), ('y'), ('z');

INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE(YOUR_FIELD)
SELECT C
FROM TEMP_CHARS
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(T1.C, T2.C) -- Generate all variations (with repetition) of length 2.
FROM TEMP_CHARS T1 CROSS JOIN TEMP_CHARS T2
UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(T1.C, T2.C, T3.C) -- Generate all variations (with repetition) of length 3.
FROM TEMP_CHARS T1 CROSS JOIN TEMP_CHARS T2 CROSS JOIN TEMP_CHARS T3;

DROP TABLE TEMP_CHARS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is pretty easy if you aware join = cartesian product,
the below (an alternative version from using a user defined function @Branko Dimitrijevic),
you can put into a text file (join.sql) :-

```
create table abc ( a char(3) );
create table a ( a char(1) );
insert into a values ('a','b' ..., 'z');

insert into abc select a from a;

insert into abc
select concat(a.a, b.a) from a
join a as b;

insert into abc
select concat(a.a, b.a, c.a) from a
join a as b
join a as c;
```

And pipe into mysql

```
mysql -u xxx -h xxx < join.sql
```